# How do I run the Facebook Fasttext

Tags: facebook, python-2.7, deep-learning

I just installed the Fasttext package from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fasttext.
I then tried the example from the site:

```
import fasttext

# Skipgram model
model = fasttext.skipgram('data.txt', 'model')
print model.words # list of words in dictionary

# CBOW model
model = fasttext.cbow('data.txt', 'model')
print model.words # list of words in dictionary
```

I however got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/tryfasttext.py", line 1, in <module>
    import fasttext
ImportError: No module named fasttext
```

What could be the problem? How can I sort it out.
N/B 
Am new to this deep learning stuff though.
Am using python 2.7, on windows 10, 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

I account the same problem when I test my installation of fasttext. 
In my case (under ubuntu 14.04), I solve it by installing Cython.

```
$ pip install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile"
```

then install fasttext again

```
$pip install fasttext
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi sorry for a very very late reply. I had moved to other options though. I recently installed Cython and it worked for me....but this: model = fasttext.skipgram('data.txt', 'model')
  File "fasttext/fasttext.pyx", line 242, in fasttext.fasttext.skipgram (fasttext/fasttext.cpp:5863)
  File "fasttext/fasttext.pyx", line 186, in fasttext.fasttext.train_wrapper (fasttext/fasttext.cpp:4770)
ValueError: fastText: cannot load data.txt

Answer (score 0):

**What could be the problem?**

**Answer:** It could be several things.

1. You don't have the necessary C compiler installed.
2. You've installed fasttext in the wrong spot on your computer.
3. Your command line/terminal may be referencing a default python package and you've install fasttext to another...

**How can I sort it out.** Options:

1. Learn about environment management...
2. Use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) to manage python and all dependencies...(this is what I do and I never deal with these issues anymore.)

**EDIT:**

I tried using a python port of FastText, but found it to be buggy...so I ran it from the command line as shown on Facebook's page and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. I have just moved from windows to Ubuntu with some success. But I just go into this: ValueError: fastText: cannot load data.txt. what data is used?

Comment: I wouldn't use that package...I had some issues with it yesterday. I'd run it from the command line. Let me know if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @wakamdr Have you got any solution for what "data.txt" is used? Any other clues for fasttext+python are also welcome.